# How to create a new column with multiple values in python dataframe using for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I want to create a function with a for loop that iterates through a small dataframe and adds a new column with different values depending on the conditions set.

I have tried the below, but it returns the output for my first if statement for all the rows (it prints 'Top Buyers' for every row):

```
def CustomerSegmentClassifier(df):
    
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (df['Recency'] <= 200).any() or (df['Frequency'] >= 20).any():
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Top Buyers'
        elif (df['Recency'].between(201, 750)).any() or (df['Frequency'].between(5,19)).any():
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Casual Buyers'
        else:
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Churned Buyers'
    return df
```

[Image of Output from CustomerSegmentClassifer Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kQRP.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my try to solve your question :

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_csv('test_data.txt', sep=',', header=None)
#df.columns = ['Customer ID','Recency','Frequency','Monetary Value']

def CustomerSegmentClassifier(df):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (df['Recency'][i] <= 200) or (df['Frequency'][i] >= 20):
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Top Buyers'
        elif (200 > df['Recency'][i] <= 750) or (5 > df['Frequency'][i] < 20):
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Casual Buyers'
        else:
            df.at[i,'Cluster Name'] = 'Churned Buyers'
    return df

CustomerSegmentClassifier(df)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Avoid for-loops across rows for vectorized methods. Unlike general purpose Python using lists and dicts, pandas and numpy have several solutions for conditional logic on arrays and series.

Specifically, for your needs consider [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and even use Series operators for inequality logic:

```py
def CustomerSegmentClassifier(df): 
    conditions = [
        ((df['Recency'].le(200)) | (df['Frequency'].ge(20))),
        (
          (df['Recency'].between(201, 750)) |
          (df['Frequency'].between(5, 19))
        )
    ]

    values = ['Top Buyers', 'Casual Buyers']

    df['Cluster Name'] = np.select(
        conditions, values, default='Churned Buyers'
    )
    
    return df
```

Comment: Glad to help! But please heed the *very* important note of avoiding row-wise loops which should be avoided in pandas.